# Are *.pdb files bound to a specific compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, pdb-files

I need my release `*.exe` to generate `*.pdb` files in order to be able to analize any dump file the final user might send to me, I've already sorted that part out but I was wondering if it is necessary to save the `*.pdb` files or I can generate them with the source code; it looks like the latter. Here is what I've tried:

1. I build `*.exe` that crashes on purpose (let's call it "*`A.exe` V1*").
2. Copy "*`A.exe` V1*" to another machine.
3. Execute "*`A.exe` V1*", it crashes and creates "*`A.dmp` V1*".
4. Copy "*`A.dmp` V1*" to my machine, I can debug this dump file with no issues.
5. Delete all `*.pdb` files, try to debug "*`A.dmp` V1*" and it (expectedly) complains with the message "*Debugging information for 'A.exe' cannot be found or does not match*".
6. **Without changing a single character in any source file** rebuild the program (let's call it "*`A.exe` V2*") now I have freshly created `*.pdb` files<sup>1</sup>.
7. Try to debug "*`A.dmp` V1*" and it (unexpectedly) complains with the message "*Debugging information for 'A.exe' cannot be found or does not match*".
8. If I copy "*`A.exe` V2*" to the other machine, generate a new dump ("*`A.dmp` V2*") then I can debug "*`A.dmp` V2*" with no issues.

So the question is: *Are `*.pdb` files bound to a specific compilation? or I'm doing something wrong?*

---

<sup>1</sup>This new `*.pdb` files have a different size compared to the previous ones!?

[image]

Comment: _"...So the question is: Are *.pdb files bound to a specific compilation? ..."_ Yes and also no.  If you rebuild with __exactly__ the same source, source path and compiler/linker options they should work and you can force them to load if the IDE complains.  Usually when making a release (anything that leaves my computer) I tag (or whatever) in source control and package the released program (etc) and PDBs together,

Comment: Probably the same compiler and windows SDK version as well, much safer to archive the PDBs than to find you can't exactly replicate your build environment in 6 months time when you need to debug a problem

Comment: @RichardCritten there's no code change between "*`A.exe` V1*" and "*`A.exe` V2*", I've just rebuild the whole project with the same source without any code changes.